# INTERFACE target-link-libraries for shared libraries in macOS

Tags: macos, cmake

I'm creating some dynamic libraries (actually BLAS and LAPACK) with CMake. LAPACK uses functions from BLAS, but at least on Linux I don't need to specify this for building the libraries, and something like this seems to work:

```
add_library(blas ${BLAS_SOURCES})
add_library(lapack ${LAPACK_SOURCES})
# anything that links to lapack must link to blas too
target_link_libraries(lapack INTERFACE blas)
```

However, when I tried this on macOS I got undefined symbols when building lapack, which means I had to add:

```
target_link_libraries(lapack PRIVATE blas) # or "PUBLIC" and remove "INTERFACE"
```

Can this behavior be changed? Did the above work on Linux just by chance?

EDIT: This is a full simple example:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
set (CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
project (hello LANGUAGES Fortran)
add_library (bar SHARED bar.f90)
add_library (foo SHARED foo.f90)
target_link_libraries (foo INTERFACE bar)
add_executable (main main.f90)
target_link_libraries (main PUBLIC bar foo)
```

bar.f90

```
subroutine bar
write(6,*) "Hello, I'm bar"
end subroutine bar
```

foo.f90

```
subroutine foo
call bar()
end subroutine foo
```

main.f90

```
program main
call foo()
end program main
```

Comment: Why do you use `INTERFACE` linkage? This linkage means that only **consumers** of `lapack` library will be linked with the `blas`. But `lapack` library **itself** requires this linkage ("LAPACK uses functions from BLAS"). Probably, your variant works on Linux just because it creates **static** libraries by default, not *shared* ones. If you want to create shared libraries, specify your intention explicitly: `add_library(blas SHARED ${BLAS_SOURCES})`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am creating shared libraries in Linux too. I should also point out that this `lapack` library is "private" in the sense that it's used only by targets build in the same project, it's not intended to be used by other projects. My thought was that it's only when I compile an executable that I'd need to specify *which* specific BLAS library to use.

Comment: "I am creating shared libraries in Linux too." - But the code you show us demonstrates the opposite: it creates **static** `blas` and `lapack`. When called without STATIC/SHARED option, `add_library` uses some default type of the library. And on Linux this default is **static**. "My thought was that it's only when I compile an executable that I'd need to specify which specific BLAS library to use." - No, when create a **shared** library, all linked libraries should be known. Only when create a *static* library one could omit linking libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "If no type is given explicitly the type is STATIC or SHARED based on whether the current value of the variable BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is ON." I have set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON elsewhere, and I can see `*.so` files are created. The question then is what is the point of INTERFACE link (shared) libraries, if any? Is it just just a way "bundling" things that are commonly used together but are not strictly dependent?

Comment: I see a little reason for link a **shared** library with anything using INTERFACE linkage. But when your library is an INTERFACE one (e.g. header-only library), then it could be linked using INTERFACE linkage. In that case, any other linkage has a little sense.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've added a full example to the question. I'm certainly willing to accept that I should use PUBLIC instead of INTERFACE, but the fact is this works fine on Linux, is that by design or by chance?

Comment: CMake should blame (warns) you when one of your `target_link_libraries` call uses a **keyword** (PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE) and another doesn't: [CMP0023](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/policy/CMP0023.html). It is better to be consistent in that keyword usage.

Comment: Only when they're different calls for the same target. And I didn't think it would matter much for an executable. Anyway, adding PUBLIC to the last call doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Actually, it is difference in the nature of shared libraries on Linux (`.so`) and on MacOS (`.dlyb`). MacOS cannot load a shared library which uses a symbol defined neither in the library nor in the linked libraries. Linux is able to load such library as a part of **executable**, if executable itself is linked with every needed library. So the situation is not "why INTERFACE linkage works on Linux" but "why **absence of linking** works on Linux". You could remove the line `target_link_libraries (foo INTERFACE bar)`, and your code still would work on Linux and still would fail on MacOS.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, that explains it better. In my experience, INTERFACE helps on Linux to get the order of libraries right.